# Abnormal mathematical operation in C

Tags: c

I've found this question somewhere and couldn't understand it. Please help me out with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main(){

    char x = 250;

    int ans = x + !x + ~x + ++x;

    printf("%d", ans);


}
```

The output comes out to be -6. I don't understand how the compiler performs operation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that `char` is signed, note that `250` is out of range but could be  `-6`. But the `++x` without a sequence point makes it *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to understand something like this, it's often helpful to break the problem down into smaller pieces and look at each one. I modified your program so that it prints each of the values:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char x = 250;

    printf("x:   %d\n", x);
    printf("!x:  %d\n", !x);
    printf("~x:  %d\n", ~x);
    printf("++x: %d\n", ++x);

    int ans = x + !x + ~x + ++x;

    printf("ans: %d\n", ans);
}
```

And the output I get when I run it is:

```
x:   -6
!x:  0
~x:  5
++x: -5
ans: -5
```

Once you understand what each part means, it's easier to see how they combine into the final result. However, my compiler also emits a warning because `++x` modifies `x` in the same expression that uses `x` in other places, and changing the order in which the terms are evaluated will change the final result.

Comment: Even though this advice is helpful, your answer gives the impression that the blend of operations describes defined behaviour. It doesn't (at least not when combined erratically).